# send result of ajax call as a parameter to another function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, callback

I want to send the result of ajax call as parameter to the another function in the other acript file. Here I am able to get result in the firebug -> net-> xhr -> response.
But could not able send that data to the another function as a parameter. plz help me

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/GetFromCities/",
        type: "POST", dataType: "json",
        data: {},
        success: function (res) {
            LoadCities(JSON.parse(res));
        }
    });

});
```

Method in Controller:

```
public JsonResult GetFromCities()
    {
        Dimensions objDimensions = new Dimensions();
        TYSLayer.TYService.City[] cities = objDimensions.GetFromCities();

        var list1 = from p in cities
                    select p.CityName;

        return Json(list1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this.  what does res look like that you are trying to send?

Comment: might be that Ajax failed? Try adding error status function too.  .done(function() {
alert( "success" );
})
.fail(function() {
alert( "error" );
})

Comment: Ajax call was successss...

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to explicitly use `JSON.parse(res)` since you are expecting a `json` by setting `dataType: "json"`.

Please make sure you are sending a data from server in a valid JSON format.

Comment: @Rajesh, can you please update the json data you receive in your question?